# Vuejs3 + Firebase/ firestore causes app delay signInWithRedirect

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

I have a Vuejs.3 app that connects to firebase.

In my login view, I am using `signInWithRedirect` like so:

```
  methods: {
    signin() {
      signInWithRedirect(auth, provider)
    },
  },
```

I then have in my `mounted` cycle the returned result:

```
mounted() {
    getRedirectResult(auth)
      .then((result) => {
 
        const fbUserID = result.user.uid;
        const twitterID = result.user.providerData[0].uid;
        const twitterDisplayName = result.user.providerData[0].displayName;
        const twitterUsername = result._tokenResponse.screenName;
        const twitterPhotoURL = result.user.photoURL;
        

        const userDocument = doc(firestore, 'users', fbUserID)
        const userDocumentData = {
          twitterID: twitterID,
          twitterDisplayName: twitterDisplayName,
          twitterUsername: twitterUsername,
          twitterPhotoURL: twitterPhotoURL,
          lastLogin: Date.now()
        }

        setDoc(userDocument, userDocumentData, { merge: true} )

        
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
```

It all works but it seems very slow. My app is a very new vue app with a div and a button so I dont think there is much to load.

This is the flow that happens

1. user views login page and clicks button
2. directed to twitter and back again
3. user is sent back to login page (but there is still the login form for 3/5 seconds before authenticating).

I cant seem to figure out how to handle this delay.

I have tried created a `status` of `loading` in the state which I fire the moment `getRedirectResult` is fired. However there is still a 3/5 second delay.

How do you handle this so that I can show a "loading" icon until the app has registered the user?